# Exibir do maior para o menor (php + json)

Tags: php

Pessoal criei um foreach para ler um resultado JSON:

```
foreach($results['results']['collection1'] as $collection) {
echo $collection['nome'] . "<br />";
echo $collection['cat'] . "<br />";
echo $collection['nota'] . "<br />";
}
```

Como faço para que os resultados apareçam sempre do maior para o menor? Levando em consideração a chave "nota", é ela que irá definir as posições dos resultados.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo? Você tem um array `$collection['nota'][1], $collection['nota'][2], $collection['nota'][0]` e quer ordenar em *2,1,0*, é isso?

Comment: @PapaCharlie isso, só que a NOTA vem dentro de um JSON. "results": {
    "collection1": [
      {
        "nota": "3,8",

Comment: O primeiro passo seria passar o JSON para array, depois usar um `for` para reordenar de acordo com a *nota*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testado usando os seguintes dados de teste:

```
// dados de teste
$results = array(
    'results' => array(
        'collection1' => array(
            array('nome' => 'a', 'cat' => '', 'nota' => 2),
            array('nome' => 'b', 'cat' => '', 'nota' => 1),
            array('nome' => 'c', 'cat' => '', 'nota' => 3),
            array('nome' => 'd', 'cat' => '', 'nota' => 4),
            array('nome' => 'e', 'cat' => '', 'nota' => 5),
            array('nome' => 'f', 'cat' => '', 'nota' => 6)
        )
    )
);
```

Você quer quase exatamente o primeiro exemplo de http://php.net/manual/change.php?page=pt_BR%2Ffunction.usort.php :

```
// função de comparação
function compara_nota($a, $b) {
    if ($a['nota'] == $b['nota']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['nota'] > $b['nota']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($results['results']['collection1'], "compara_nota"); // ordena

foreach ($results['results']['collection1'] as $c) {
    echo $c['nome'] . "<br />";
    echo $c['cat'] . "<br />";
    echo $c['nota'] . "<br />";
}
```

Se não quiser modificar o array que representa o JSON, crie outro array:

```
$conjunto = $results['results']['collection1'];

// função de comparação
function compara_nota($a, $b) {
    if ($a['nota'] == $b['nota']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['nota'] > $b['nota']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($conjunto, "compara_nota"); // ordena

foreach ($conjunto as $c) {
    echo $c['nome'] . "<br />";
    echo $c['cat'] . "<br />";
    echo $c['nota'] . "<br />";
}
```

Um exemplo mais sofisticado que define qual a chave utilizada na chamada pode ser encontrado em http://php.net/manual/change.php?page=en%2Ffunction.usort.php , exemplo número 4, porém o exemplo mostra só comparação de strings (somente na versão em inglês).

Comment: Perfeito, usei o 2o exemplo para não alterar o array do JSON. E também modifiquei o sinal aqui: return ($a['nota'] < $b['nota']) ? -1 : 1; para return ($a['nota'] > $b['nota']) ? -1 : 1; Desta forma foi do maior para o menor, antes tava do menor para o menor. Obg. @fbiazi

Comment: @GustavoCave Verdade! ao escrever esqueci desta parte de ordenar do maior para o menor, vou editar a resposta para ficar adequada à pergunta.